# Trying to code in a VM command but it give me a "Use expression body for properties"

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this in my XAML:

```xml
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapGestureForUpdateCategories, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}" CommandParameter="false" />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

I have this in my ViewModel:

```cs
    public Command TapGestureForUpdateCategories
    {
        get
        {
            return new Command(val => {
                App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val);
            });
        }
    }
```

It's giving me an error on the line starting with App.DB.  saying "Use expression body for properties"

Can someone give me some idea what I might be doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Comment: I don't think it is an error - it should probably be a suggestion or a warning - unless you have 'Treat warnings as errors' set in your project. You can remove it by using `public Command TapGestureForUpdateCategories => new Command(val => App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val));`

Comment: Hi Sharada,  what if I have two actions such as App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val); and App.DB.UpdateAllCategory(val); How would I combine both into your suggestion. Also can you add your comment as an answer.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is an error - it should probably be a suggestion or a warning - unless you have 'Treat warnings as errors' set in your project.

You can remove it by using:

```
public Command TapGestureForUpdateCategories => 
     new Command(val => App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val));
```

Or,

```
public Command TapGestureForUpdateCategories => new Command(val =>
{
    App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val);
    App.DB.UpdateAllCategory(val);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Sharada,  I will accept this answer.  I do have another question as I get a message cannot convert an object to bool when it comes to val.  I will open up another question about this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46311528/xaml-viewmodel-command-parameter-cannot-convert-from-object-to-bool

Comment: Regarding business logic.  I opened another related question earlier and would value your opinion on how you fit business logic (could apply to this question also) into a ViewModel or if you move it into another file and if so then how do you instantiate that business logic class.  Here's the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46304488/where-do-i-put-my-business-logic-in-the-viewmodel-in-code-behind-or-where

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

In your ViewModel:

```cs
public class MainPageViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ICommand TapGestureForUpdateCategories { get; set; }

    public MainPageViewModel()
    {
        TapGestureForUpdateCategories = new Command(Tap);
    }

    private void Tap()
    {
       App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val);
    }

}
```

You should create a property for this purpose.