# XAML > ViewModel Command parameter - Cannot convert from object to bool?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapGestureForUpdateCategories, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}" CommandParameter="false" />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

and this code in my ViewModel

```
public Command TapGestureForUpdateCategories => new Command(val =>
{
    App.DB.UpdateAllCategoryGroups(val);
    App.DB.UpdateAllCategory(val);
});
```

I am trying to pass the parameter true or false from the XAML but in the command C# code there is a line under val saying "Cannot convert from object to bool".  Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modify as below , we can define the type we want by **x:type** inside TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameter

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapGestureForUpdateCategories, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}">
        <TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameter>
            <x:Boolean>True</x:Boolean>
        </TapGestureRecognizer.CommandParameter>
    </TapGestureRecognizer>
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approach

```
<Label.GestureRecognizers>
    <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapGestureForUpdateCategories, Source={x:Reference MainPage}}" CommandParameter="{x:Boolean False}" />
</Label.GestureRecognizers>
```